# Possible click fraud?

Tags: google-analytics, click-tracking

So I'm getting hundreds of hits (per month) across multiple separate domains, all originating from one city with 100% bounce rate and 0:00 time spent on the site. I know hundreds of clicks per month isn't that much; is it just some web crawler that Google Analytics isn't identifying?

Comment: It's possible are you seeing a rise in page views without a corresponding rise in unique visit count? Do you have any security scan or up time monitoring services running on the site?

Comment: Is this PPC traffic? Because if it's not, I don't see much point in click fraud.

Comment: Agree with @Lèsemajesté . It's probably just a bot running through your pages. Bots that execute javascript are not very common but they exist

Comment: Where are you seeing this? The fact you say click fraud indicates AdWords (or some form of paid for marketing) but if not (as per Lese Majeste) it's not click fraud.

When you say you're getting hits form multiple domains, do you mean domains you own? Could it be a DoS attack?

Answer (score 1):

I tend to side with the previous respondents, but bounce rate and time-on-site do factor into organic listings so, depending on your hosting you may be able to block by IP if you are especially concerned about it.

That said, a bit of time and wisdom (as in less than 2 years...don't judge), has helped me realize that short-term fluctuations--be it crawl/users/competitors (trying to game the system) etc.--are, in most cases, insignificant in the big picture. I nearly refuse to look at reports like "the last 7 days" anymore due to their capacity to induce stress and be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Could be.  I have a site which runs affiliate ads.  We serve those ads via Google DFP, so to novice fraudsters the ads could easily be mistaken for CPC ads due to their doubleclick.com click-through URL.

Some of these affiliate ads have CTR's well over 90%!

I can only assume that someone somewhere is banging away on those ads hoping to cost a competitor money.  (Which of course, doesn't work because the ads aren't CPC)

If these actually were CPC ads, needless to say, it would be a very expensive and very unproductive campaign.